# Python sort none ignore (or stable)

Tags: python, sorting, nonetype

I have lists whose items are either numbers or `None`.

I want to sort them, so that the `None` items stay at the same place, while the numerical values get sorted.

For example, I want this list:

```
[None, None, 20, None, 10]
```

to be sorted into:

```
[None, None, 10, None, 20]
```

and this one:

```
[None, 50, 20, None, None]
```

into:

```
[None, 20, 50, None, None]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain your stable sort like this:

- first sort the values that are not None
- then create the output list:

  - if the original list item was None, the output item is None
  - if it was a numerical value, we take the next value in the sorted list

Taking the next value from the sorted list can be easily done by creating an iterator on it, then calling `next` on it.

---

```
def stable_sort(lst):
    sorted_values = sorted([value for value in lst if value is not None])
    it_sorted = iter(sorted_values)
    out = []
    for value in lst:
        out.append(None if value is None else next(it_sorted))
    return out

print(stable_sort([None, None, 20, None, 10]))
# [None, None, 10, None, 20]

print(stable_sort([None, 50, 20, None, None]))
# [None, 20, 50, None, None]
```